# The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed with WCF service in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, wshttpbinding

I'm having trouble deploying my WCF Service. Everything worked fine on the development machine. However, when I'm trying to host it on a server with IIS over the http port 80. I'm getting security problems.

Just copying it over produced an error `The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed`, and I noticed that my dns identity was:

```
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
```

So I changed that to:

```
      <identity>
        <dns value="ServerName"/>
      </identity>
```

However, I'm now getting `The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed` (so it seems it got past the DNS identity, problem). This is the service in my web.config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFDataInterface.Service">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFDataInterface.IService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="ServerName"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Can anyone help with the setting this up? All the resources I can find on the internet just seem to add confusion. I can't find any way to get past this authentication problem hosting a wsHttpBinding service.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many solutions, I think I've got things working in the meantime at least by setting the security mode to none:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>      
    <binding name="myBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">         
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None" />
      <reliableSession enabled="true" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```